# vim tagbar how to generate proper ruby DSL structure

Tags: ruby, vim, ctags

If I using `grape` to build http api like following ruby code:

```
module Twitter
  class API < Grape::API

    helpers do
      def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.authorize!(env)
      end

      def authenticate!
        error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
      end
    end

    resource :statuses do
      desc 'Return a public timeline.'
      get :public_timeline do
        ...
      end

      desc 'Return a personal timeline.'
      get :home_timeline do
        ...
      end


      desc 'Create a status.'
      post do
        ...
      end

      desc 'Update a status.'
      put ':id' do
        ...
      end

      desc 'Delete a status.'
      delete ':id' do
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I expect vim `tagbar` plugin show generate proper structure, but it not, like following screenshot:

[image]

It only treat `def` as a structure of the code. How to make tagbar treat `resource`, `dsec` as a structure?

Comment: Tagbar relies on ctags, which isn't planed for ruby, especially those DSL.

Comment: @halfelf is there ctags like alternative for ruby tags